# JavaScript prints the entire array instead of single element

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var inventory = ["jacket","pants","map"];
var actionsIKnow = ["north","east","west","south"];
var messages = ["A group of dangerous minions. Turn back, you do not have a sword",
  "You have gone too deep into the forest. Want to go further?",
  "A giant ruby crystal",
  "A silent lake; you see your reflection in the water",
  "Clear patch of land",
  "A sleeping dragon. Bettwe not wake it up",
  "A solitary cottage. Faint music can be heard from the inside",
  "Looks like this path leads to the cottage of the flute maker",
  "A lot of tombstones, looks like an old graveyard"
];

var userInput;
var startingPos = 4;

button.addEventListener("click",takeMeThere,false);

function takeMeThere(){
  userInput = input.value;
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if(userInput!=null){
    validateInput();
  }
}
function validateInput(){
  for(var i=0;i<actionsIKnow.length;i++){
    if(userInput.indexOf(actionsIKnow[i]!=-1)){
      move(actionsIKnow[i]);
    }
  }
}
function move(where){
  console.log(where);
}
```

I am making a text based exploring game where the user can select where to go. Where the user wants to go depends on what was entered in the textfield. This data is then passed to `move(where)` where I `console.log(where)`. Instead of printing north, east, etc it prints the whole of `actionsIKnow` array. Why ?

Comment: Not the problem, but note that the test `if(userInput!=null){` will _never_ be false.

Comment: @nnnnnn why ? How do I check if user enter empty ?

Comment: The `.value` attribute returns a _string,_ and the string method `.toLowerCase()` also returns a string. To test that the field is not empty compare to an empty string: `if (userInput!=""){`. You may also like to first trim any white space: `userInput = userInput.replace(/\s/g,"");`, in case the user enters nothing but spaces...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple mistake. Change

```
if(userInput.indexOf(actionsIKnow[i]!=-1)){
```

to this:

```
if (userInput.indexOf(actionsIKnow[i]) !== -1 ) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bz8k5/

*Edit. As per discussion in comments.* To be able to validate input in different format like east, move east, but disallow easter you may also want to make use of more sophisticated validation rules. Maybe using regular expressions:

```
if (userInput.match(new RegExp("\\b" + actionsIKnow[i] + "\\b"))) {
    move(actionsIKnow[i]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bz8k5/2/

Comment: +1. You just beat me - guess I shouldn't have "wasted" time creating a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HuyaT/

Comment: @nnnnnn ))) I created a fiddle after I answered.

Comment: Enter "feasting" into the input box and click Go. It prints "east". Should it?

Comment: Further to what Michael said, the user might enter "North East", and then it would print both "north" and "east" - is that right? (More a question for the OP than for dfsq...)

Comment: @MichaelGeary Right, this is how OP searches the value in the array. Of course it still needs some work. For example I would use `indexof` method of the array. http://jsfiddle.net/bz8k5/1/ But this is another question.

Comment: It happened again: four seconds after your last comment I posted a comment about the array `.indexOf()` under the other answer...

Comment: Why is this voted up as an answer?
What LittleChild needed was 
`userInput == actionsIKnow[i]` as Michael Geary mentioned.

Comment: @PrathameshGharat Post it as answer and I will personally upvote it.

Comment: @PrathameshGharat - Why shouldn't it be upvoted? It pointed out the very simple mistake in the OP's code, and the fix for it. I'm not saying Michael's answer isn't good too, but maybe the OP wants to let the user type something like "Move north", in which case using `.indexOf()` would be right and `==` would be wrong.

Comment: @PrathameshGharat So we together answered this question. I was the first to spot the indexOf problem, MichaelGeary noted about another potential problem and proposed a solution. In comments I suggested using `Array.indexOf` if needed, MichaelGeary `==`. So OP now has all the info to move further himself. We both deserved some upvotes, I guess,you disagree?

Comment: @nnnnnn - Excellent point about input like "move north". OTOH, I think if OP does want more flexible input like that, it may require a bit different validation. For example, "north-northwest" prints "north" (but only once) and "west". One might expect that to turn into two moves north and one move west. In any case, it's been a pleasure to collaborate with you on this! :-)

Comment: @sfsq My bad, sorry, I see what you mean now, So if the user types `north east` it will execute north and then east. Taking back the down vote. P.S. Can you edit the answer? I cant upvote it, its locked until its edited.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Right, I think the optimal check would be using Regexp: `if (userInput.match(new RegExp("\\b" + actionsIKnow[i] + "\\b"))) {` http://jsfiddle.net/bz8k5/2/. So it'd allow `east`, `move east`, but not `easter`.

Answer (score 3):

Look closely at this line of code:

```
if(userInput.indexOf(actionsIKnow[i]!=-1)){
```

Let's add spaces to make it easier to see:

```
if( userInput.indexOf( actionsIKnow[i]!=-1 ) ) {
```

See it yet? Let's turn the spaces into newlines and indent:

```
if(
    userInput.indexOf(
        actionsIKnow[i] != -1
    )
) {
```

Now do you see the problem? :-)

Anyway, what you probably really meant here is simply:

```
if( userInput == actionsIKnow[i] ) {
```

Or, as @nnnnnn suggested, you can use `.indexOf()` *instead* of your own loop, like this:

```
function validateInput(){
    if( actionsIKnow.indexOf(userInput) >= 0  ) {
        move( userInput );
    }
}
```

But beware of one problem: `.indexOf()` on an array is not available in IE8 and earlier versions of IE. If you need to support IE8, this won't work.

So here is my favorite way to do it: Use an object lookup instead of an array.

Change `actionsIKnow` to:

```
var actionsIKnow = { north:1, east:1, west:1, south:1 };
```

and then change `validateInput()` to:

```
function validateInput(){
    if( userInput in actionsIKnow ) {
        move( userInput );
    }
}
```

This works in all browsers, and if there were a large number of items in `actionsIKnow`, this object lookup would be much faster than `.indexOf()`. For a small number of items the performance wouldn't matter, but I think the `in` operator makes for the nicest reading code.

Here's a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/object-lookup-vs-indexof) that compares performance between `.indexOf()` and `in` for a large number of strings.

Comment: In your updated function that uses the `in` operator, what is `i`? Should be `move(userInput)`...

Comment: Oops, sorry about the typo, just fixed it. The function doesn't use `i` at all any more. It doesn't need to loop.

Comment: Cool. Even with an array the OP could skip the loop and just use the [array `.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: Very true. Of course `.indexOf()` *does* loop, it just does it for you. If you were checking against a very large dictionary of words, putting them in an object and testing with the `in` operator should be faster than `.indexOf()`. But for a small array performance would be fine either way.

Comment: Michael, how sure are you that the object is faster? Doesn't it have to loop just the same, under the covers?

Comment: @ErikE - good question! So I made a [jsperf for it](http://jsperf.com/object-lookup-vs-indexof). If you have a large number of items, the `in` operator on an object is *much* faster than `.indexOf()`. This makes sense because objects are generally implemented as hash tables or other structures with similar performance. The `in` operator definitely doesn't have to loop over the entire object. The jsperf also tests `.hasOwnProperty()` on the object, which in most browsers performs about the same as `in`, but in Chrome is very slow - almost as slow as `.indexOf()` on the array.